# How can i copy a class to another class both from a base interface?

Tags: c#

Here is the base interface:

```
public interface Group
{
  string GroupName { get; set; }
}
```

And Here is the first class

```
public class GroupOne:Group
{
  string _GroupName;
            public string GroupName
            {
                set { _GroupName = value; }
                get { return _GroupName; }
            }
}
```

And here is the second class

```
public class GroupTwo:Group,INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
      public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
            private void NotifyPropertyChange(string propertyName)
            {
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
                }
            }
string _GroupName;
            public string GroupName
            {
                get
                {
                    return _GroupName;
                }
                set
                {
                    _GroupName = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChange("GroupName");
                }
            }
    }
```

Finally:

```
GroupOne G1=new GroupOne();
G1.GroupName="123";
GroupTwo G2;
```

These are examples,actually the interface has more than 80 property but not only the 'GroupName' one.How can I copy all the property base on interface 'Group' from 'G1' to 'G2'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are opened on using Reflection, the following code might help you accomplishing the copy:

```
static void ReflectionMerge<T>(T source, T target)
    where T: class
{
    var properties = typeof(T).
        GetProperties().
        Where(x => x.CanRead && x.CanWrite);

    foreach(var property in properties)
    {
        var sourceValue = property.GetValue(source);
        property.SetValue(target, sourceValue);
    }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
GroupOne G1 = new GroupOne();
G1.GroupName = "123";
GroupTwo G2 = new GroupTwo();

ReflectionMerge<Group>(G1, G2);
```

It is to be noted Reflection is not the most efficient way of accomplishing merging/cloning.

You can always go for a solution like the one below:

```
public static void MergeWith(this Group target, Group source)
{
    target.GroupName = source.GroupName;
    // target.Foo = source.Foo;
    // target.Bar = source.Bar;
}
```

Comment: It works!Thank you! Is the Reflection method using linq?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`AutoMapper`](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) for your type mapping. While @StfBln answer is certainly a valid approach, AutoMapper actually simplifies this manual conversion. This can come in especially handy, when converting more than one object pair.
Of course you have to do some setup first (see [How do I use AutoMapper?](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Getting-started#how-do-i-use-automapper) to get started), but you can easily resue and expand this (also in other projects).

So for your usecase a mapping could look like this:

```
Mapper.Map<GroupTwo>(g1);
```

Setting up you mapping could look like this:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<GroupOne, GroupTwo>());
```

or if you want to put it into a separate profile for easy expansion ...

```
public class MyAutoMapperProfile : Profile
{
    CreateMap<GroupOne, GroupTwo>();
}
```

... and then your registration would look like this:

```
Mapper.Initialize(config => config.AddProfile<MyAutoMapperProfile>());
```

Comment: Thank you!AutoMapper is a effective approach!